# How to use Cyrillic in Dev-C++ for C language

Tags: c, cyrillic

I try to use Cyrillic in Dev-C++ when writing program with programming language C, but when start console are printed some symbols like "?" for example.

I use the line `system("chcp 1251>nul")`, but it not working.

Did you know how can print Cyrillic letters in console? What code to use?

Thanks.

Comment: If you see ? in console, your output is likely UTF-8, not CP1251.

Comment: I trying to save in UTF-8, ANSI, ASCII, Unicode and etc. but without result.